# Divi blog grid display title on hover

Tags: wordpress, grid, blogs, elementor, divi

I'm actually using the Divi Visual Builder and I would like display a blog grid who show title of each posts on the image of the posts only when you move the mouse over it.
I found some solutions on the web, but either it doesn't work at all, or the effect doesn't work in tablet and mobile displays. There is nothing about this on the Divi MarketPlace for the Blog module.
here is an example of what I would like to do : http://www.artazoi.com/murs-a-programmation/
(this website is using the Bakery Page Builder and I don't want to use it)
Do you know if Elementor Pro offers this option ?
Thank you all for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple DIVI Builder Blog Module with position absolute. Add this CSS code

```
.et_pb_module.et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper article{
  position: relative;
}
.et_pb_module.et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper article .entry-title{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.et_pb_module.et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper article:hover .entry-title{
  display: block;
}
```